# Mediacodec jelly-bean

Tags: android, mp4, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm working with media codec for an .mp4 file on jelly-bean and getting this in logcat

```
02-27 12:12:13.645: A/ACodec(6760): frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:1041 CHECK(def.nBufferSize >= size) failed.
02-27 12:12:13.645: A/libc(6760): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 6778 (CodecLooper)
```

Can anyone tell me what is this?
and how to solve it?

Comment: have you found any solution? I also got this in some specific devices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You provided not much info, so the answer follows:

Looks like it is internal check of libstagefright library.

I faced same error on Samsung Tab 2 on decoder's configuration.

```
mDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
```

After the decoder is created it is configured by input format received from the extractor(aka demuxer)

```
MediaFormat inputFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);

mDecoder.configure(inputFormat, null, null, 0); // <-- crashes here
```

Fix (place it before mDecoder.configure):

```
inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 0);
```

Comment: Yes,That was the problem(Max_input_size).I forgot to post the solution.